# Using Python and Google Cloud to connect to multiple Google Workspace Domains

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-workspace

I am about to start a project and I wanted to first make sure it was possible. The end goal is to leverage Python Scripts in GCP to connect to multiple Google Workspace instances to do things like add members/managers to Groups. Is this possible?

Example: I own domain1.com and domain2.com
As an Admin, I choose the appropriate domain, then specify the Group and the user to add to the Group and push the go button. Then, the tool I build would look at the domain I chose to work in, and send the command to that domain adding the user to the appropriate Group.

I just want to make sure it is possible to connect multiple domains.

Thank you!

Josh

Comment: Yes, it's possible. I encourage you to read Google's extensive documentation [Enhance Workspace Apps](https://developers.google.com/workspace) and [Google Workspace Admin SDK: Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/quickstart/python). Your question includes no code which is a "smell
 for not meeting the site's guidelines.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Great! Thank you DazWilkin! That is exactly what I needed to know. The reason there isn't any code is because I simply needed to verify it was possible. Thank you again! Josh